# Office 365 Management APIで AF429 エラーが発生

Tags: ms-office

**<問い合わせ内容>**

- [Office 365 Management API] で AF429 エラーが発生​
- [Office 365 Management API] を利用して [監査ログ] を収集時に下記のエラー<エラーメッセージ>​が発生しています。​
  　こちらのエラーの原因と対処方法について確認したい。​

**<エラーメッセージ>​**

> (StatusCode=Forbidden):
>   (ReasonPhrase=Forbidden):​
>   (Errorcode=AF429):​
>   (Message=Too many requests. Method=GetBlob, PublisherId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000):​

​
**<処理の流れ>​**
(1) コンテンツリストの取得​
 「subscriptions/content?contentType={ContentType}&startTime={0}&endTime={1}」のAPIを発行し、コンテンツの一覧を取得。​
  ※ このとき、パラメーターに「PublisherIdentifier=｛テナントID｝」を含めています。​
(2) 取得したコンテンツの「contentUri」を利用してコンテンツブロブの取得を試みた。​
  結果 → エラー。​
  ※ 取得しようとしてコンテンツブロブすべてエラーではありません。​
  (複数コンテンツブロブを順番に取得している途中でエラーとなっています。)​
   このとき、最大 2 同時のコンテンツブロブを収集する仕組みとしています。(並列処理)​

**<エラー発生頻度>​**
・ある日の1日
 1 回目収集実行　エラー発生時間：01:00:38​
 2 回目収集実行　エラー発生時間：09:28:43​
 3 回目収集実行　エラー発生時間：10:40:22​
 4 回目収集実行　エラー発生せず：10:30:50
・別日の1日
 1 回目収集実行　エラー発生時間：01:00:16​
 2 回目収集実行　エラー発生せず：10:43:14​ 
  ※ 収集を実行してエラーが発生すると処理を終了しています。時間をおいて再度エラーが発生するかいなか確認を実施。​
 ​
**<質問事項>​**
■ 1. 本エラーが発生する原因と対応方法について教えて下さい。​
■ 2. API リファレンスによると、API 発行時のパラメタに「PublisherIdentifier=｛テナントID｝」を含めると専用のリソースが割り当てられ、そのリソースを利用して、API の受付処理をすると認識しています。​
  今回、上記「エラー発生時の処理内容の (1)」では、コンテンツリスト取得時に「PublisherIdentifier=｛テナントID｝」を指定しています。​
  レスポンスとして取得したコンテンツ情報を利用して上記「エラー発生時の処理内容の (2)」の処理を行っています。​
  このとき、「contentUri」はそのまま利用しており、「PublisherIdentifier=｛テナントID｝」は付加していません。​
  これは、付加する必要ないと認識していますが、あっているか確認したい。​
■ 3. 本件では、コンテンツリスト取得時に「PublisherIdentifier=｛テナントID｝」を指定しているため、1 分あたり 6 万回のリクエストを受け入られると認識していますが、あっているか確認したい。​
■ 4. 上記エラーメッセージの中に、「PublisherId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000」の内容がありました。​
  上記の「<処理の流れ>​(1) コンテンツリストの取得」の API 発行時に、「PublisherIdentifier=｛テナントID｝」を含めて API を発行しています。​
  これにより、「コンテンツブロブ」の取得 API を発行する際にも、「PublisherIdentifier」が有効となり、専用クオータが割当てられていると認識をしています。​
  「PublisherIdentifier」は有効に作用していると考えて問題ないか確認したい。​

Comment: Troubleshooting the Office 365 Management Activity API [Requesting content blobs and throttling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/troubleshooting-the-office-365-management-activity-api#requesting-content-blobs-and-throttling) の記事が参考になるかもしれません。日本語訳はいまいちのようですがこちら。[コンテンツ BLOB の要求と調整](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/office-365-management-api/troubleshooting-the-office-365-management-activity-api#requesting-content-blobs-and-throttling)

Comment: コンテンツブロブ取得用のAPIを発行する際に「PublisherIdentifier」を含めて実行してみました。この場合、「PublisherIdentifier」が有効に作用しているか否かを確認する方法はありませんでしょうか？

Comment: [Office 365 マネージメント アクティビティ API についてよく寄せられる質問](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-faq)に「マネージメント アクティビティ API で調整エラーが発生しました。 どうすればよいですか? - Microsoft サポートでチケットを開いて、新しい調整制限を要求してください。また、制限の引き上げに対する業務上の正当な理由を含めてください。 要求を審査し承諾されると、調整制限が引き上げられます。」とあり、状況や確認方法をMicrosoftサポートに聞くとか、MSDN/TechNetフォーラム等に質問してみる等をやってみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: コメントいただいた通りに改修を行いましたが、コンテンツブロブ及びコンテンツリスト取得時に同様のエラーが発生しています。
解決方法についてご教授お願いします。

■状況(改善した点)
コンテンツブロブのAPI発行時に、コメントいただいたとおりに、PublisherIdentifier=｛テナントID｝を含めることで
専用リソースを利用するようにしました。

■エラー発生状況
2020-01-08 以降、コンテンツブロブ及びコンテンツリスト取得時に(Errorcode=AF429):(Message=Too many requests）エラーの発生が継続している状況です。
コンテンツブロブの取得としては、すべて取得できない状況ではなく、アプリケーション起動後、ある程度の取得はできていますが、取得を繰り返していると
エラーとなる状況です。

■MSサポートへの連絡状況
本件、MSサポートへ確認しましたが、APIの動作についてはstack overflowに問い合わせをしてくださいと連絡受けている状況です。

Comment: いくら何でも **「APIの動作についてはstack overflowに問い合わせをしてください」** というのはおかしいでしょう。ここはMSとは関係のない独立したサイトですからMSが作成・運用しているサービスの文書化されていない詳細は答えられないでしょう。また少なくとも日本語版サイトではMSの担当者が常駐していて回答しているようには見えません。英語版サイトならばMSの関係者であると明らかにして回答やコメントを書いている人は居ますが。今のところは同様な経験と解決策を知っている人が居て、情報提供してくれるのを待つしか無いでしょうね。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。なんとも言いようがない状況ですが、状況提供待つ状況でして、同様のご経験ある方いらっしゃいましたら助かります。